# How would i add a second column to this drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, image, drop-down-menu

How would I add a second column to this drop down menu?

I'm using images instead of text. I know I've got tables in tables and images that are the wrong size etc but its just a test at the moment. If you can think of anything else to improve this menu please let me know. I hardly know anything about coding and didn't make this.

If you see anything google may not be happy with with this than please let me know as well. There's a hidden value in there and I'm not sure if that's ok with seo because I don't understand how that hidden value functions

```
<style>
    table.menu
    {
        font-size:100%;
        position:absolute;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showmenu(elmnt)
    {
       document.getElementById(elmnt).style.visibility="visible";
    }
    function hidemenu(elmnt)
    {
       document.getElementById(elmnt).style.visibility="hidden";
    }
</script>

<table border="1" cellspacing="1" width="60" height="60">
  <tr>
    <td width="60" height="60">
        <table width="60" height="60">
          <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <td onmouseover="showmenu('Graphic Design')" onmouseout="hidemenu('Graphic Design')">
               <img src="Thumbs/plus.png" width="60" height="60"><br />
               <table class="menu" id="Graphic Design" width="60">
                   <tr>
                      <td class="menu"><a href="www.techagesite.com/meboy.htm">
                        <img src="thumbs/angry-birds-iphone-4-wallpaper-mobile-05_small.jpg" width="100"   height="150">
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td class="menu"><a href="www.techagesite.com/meboy.htm">
                        <img src="thumbs/angry-birds-iphone-4-wallpaper-mobile-05_small.jpg" width="100" height="150">
                      </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
          </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, wont let me comment for some reason. Note: This is not intended to be an answer.

Tables should only really be used to store tabular data, could you provide more information as to what your trying to do. What is the drop down menu for, navigation or displaying items? The difference will determine what the appropriate controls are for your scenario.

Comment: well the drop down menu is activated on mouseover and will list images that link off the their category

Comment: there is a particular table surrounding the menu designed to stop mouse activity anywhere to the right of the menu activating the drop

Comment: Having a hard time following the table in your example

Comment: Having a hard time following the table in your example. To clarify, you have a list of categories, when a categories is moused over an image should display and then disappear on mourseout?

Comment: one menu only. hover over the image and the menu activates. in that menu i have vertical images. so im looking to add a second column besides the existing one (the code i have provided)

Answer (score 0):

Lay your images out in DIV's, for each image have an unordered list that has a class thats disabled by default and then activate through javascript on hover.

Comment: im not sure how to do that. is there a way to do it thats easier. say just copy a piece of my existing code and paste it at x position?